# Safari showing image in input file element

Tags: html, css, safari

I have a file upload element

```
<input type="file">
```

When I choose a file most browsers (i.e. Chrome and FF) display the image name. Safari however is showing a tiny thumbnail. Bad Safari!

My end goal, which is working everywhere except Safari, is to have a custom upload button using a psudo element.  After selecting an image a tiny thumbnail shows up in the center of my button that I can't seem to get rid of.

To boil down the issue:

Safari: [image: Safari showing thumbnail]

Everyone else: [image: Other browsers not showing thumbnail]

Goal after adding font-size: 0;: [image: Just the button]

To wrap it up here's the final product I'm trying to prevent: [image: Go away image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the font-size to 0 you could try `visibility: hidden;`

I assume, that your "Select Image" button is not part of the input element, so it should still be displayed.

```
input[type="file"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```